# angularjs ngmodel doesn't update view when bind to an object

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

Code below:

```
---html---
<input type="text" ng-model="pageInfo.businessHours" name="businessHours" date-formatter="object|start|end||-||HH:mm" readonly  />
---js---
...
$scope.pageInfo = {
    businessHours: {
        start: new Date(),
        end: new Date()
    }
};

// when I change businessHours, the input value doesn't update
$scope.pageInfo.businessHours.start = new Date('2000-10-10'); // view doesn't update
```

The problem is that when `$scope.pageInfo.businessHours` changed, the view never change.

(The `date-formatter` is my custom directive to show two date object as `08:10-20:30`.)

So, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding to `pageInfo.businessHours` not to `pageInfo.businessHours.start`, and those two are different, so when you reset start property `pageInfo.businessHours` didn't change as an object but start property did. so either you reset `pageInfo.businessHours` or you bind to `pageInfo.businessHours.start` property.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to bind to `pageInfo.businessHours`, and whenever `start` or `end` property changed, the ngmodel update the view. `$scope.$watchCollection('pageInfo.businessHours'` can capture property changes, so ngmodel has any kind of this methods?

Comment: Why you don't reinitialize pageInfo.businessHours to be a new object with the new start/end values every time one of start/end properties change ?

Comment: It's a solution but not that perfect. I would accept your answer if no better ones. Thanks a lot for your answer.